# How get result of function from cpp file in the main.cpp?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to get result of function from a c++ file in my main.cpp in QT.

example

.h file:

```
ifndef HOTPLUGWATCHER_GUI_H
#define HOTPLUGWATCHER_GUI_H

#include <QWidget>

class QTextBrowser;
class QSystemTrayIcon;
class QLabel;
class QPushButton;
class QToolButton;
class QDeviceWatcher;
class HotplugWatcher_GUI : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit HotplugWatcher_GUI(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~HotplugWatcher_GUI();

    void appendMessage(const QString& msg);

public slots:
    void toggleWatch();
    void showDetail(bool show);
    void slotDeviceAdded(const QString& dev);
    void slotDeviceRemoved(const QString& dev);
    void slotDeviceChanged(const QString& dev);

private:
    QDeviceWatcher *watcher;

    QLabel *state;
    QTextBrowser *msg_view;
    QPushButton *button;
    QToolButton *detail_button;
    QSystemTrayIcon *tray;
};

#endif // HOTPLUGWATCHER_GUI_H
```

cpp file:

```
#include "hotplugwatcher_gui.h"

#include <QtCore/QThread>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QMessageBox>

#include "qdevicewatcher.h"

HotplugWatcher_GUI::HotplugWatcher_GUI(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout *vbl = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    setLayout(vbl);

    state = new QLabel(this);
    //qDebug()<<state;
    button = new QPushButton(tr("Start"), this);
    detail_button = new QToolButton(this);
    detail_button->setText(tr("Detail"));
    detail_button->setCheckable(true);
    detail_button->setChecked(true);
    msg_view = new QTextBrowser(this);
    msg_view->setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::NoWrap);

    QHBoxLayout *hbl = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    hbl->addWidget(button);
    hbl->addWidget(detail_button);

    vbl->addWidget(state);
    vbl->addLayout(hbl);
    vbl->addWidget(msg_view);

    tray = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
    tray->show();

    watcher = new QDeviceWatcher;
    watcher->appendEventReceiver(this);
    connect(watcher, SIGNAL(deviceAdded(QString)), this, SLOT(slotDeviceAdded(QString)), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(watcher, SIGNAL(deviceChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(slotDeviceChanged(QString)), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(watcher, SIGNAL(deviceRemoved(QString)), this, SLOT(slotDeviceRemoved(QString)), Qt::DirectConnection);

    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(toggleWatch()));
    connect(detail_button, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), SLOT(showDetail(bool)));
}

HotplugWatcher_GUI::~HotplugWatcher_GUI()
{

}

void HotplugWatcher_GUI::appendMessage(const QString &msg)
{
    msg_view->append(msg);
}

void HotplugWatcher_GUI::toggleWatch()
{
    if (watcher->isRunning()) {
        if (!watcher->stop()) {
            QMessageBox::warning(0, tr("WARNGING"), tr("Failed to stop"));
        }
        button->setText(tr("Start"));
    } else {
        if (!watcher->start()) {
            QMessageBox::warning(0, tr("WARNGING"), tr("Failed to start"));
        }
        button->setText(tr("Stop"));
    }
}

void HotplugWatcher_GUI::showDetail(bool show)
{
    msg_view->setVisible(show);
    int w = width();
    adjustSize();  //width changes
    resize(w, height());
}

void HotplugWatcher_GUI::slotDeviceAdded(const QString &dev)
{
    qDebug("tid=%#x: add %s", (quintptr) QThread::currentThreadId(), qPrintable(dev));

    state->setText("<font color=#0000ff>Add: </font>" + dev);
    tray->showMessage(tr("New device"), dev);
}

void HotplugWatcher_GUI::slotDeviceChanged(const QString &dev)
{
    qDebug("tid=%#x: change %s", (quintptr) QThread::currentThreadId(), qPrintable(dev));

    state->setText("<font color=#0000ff>Change: </font>" + dev);
    tray->showMessage(tr("Change device"), dev);
}

void HotplugWatcher_GUI::slotDeviceRemoved(const QString &dev)
{
    qDebug("tid=%#x: remove %s", (quintptr) QThread::currentThreadId(), qPrintable(dev));

    state->setText("<font color=#0000ff>Remove: </font>" + dev);
    tray->showMessage(tr("Remove device"), dev);
}
```

and the main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "hotplugwatcher_gui.h"

static HotplugWatcher_GUI *gui = 0;

#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 0, 0)
#define qInstallMessageHandler qInstallMsgHandler
void MsgOuput(QtMsgType type, const char *msg)
{
#else
void MsgOuput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &, const QString& msg)
{
#endif
    Q_UNUSED(type)
    if (gui)
        gui->appendMessage(msg);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qInstallMessageHandler(MsgOuput);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    HotplugWatcher_GUI hotplug;
    gui = &hotplug;
    hotplug.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

So this open widgets with buttons, when push "star" button, I can see on the widgets some informations when I connect usb device.

That is good point to start.

But, I don't want to have widget but send data received to QML to work with.

First and main question, I know how call function like:

```
do_something(2,5)
```

and the function is

```
int do_something (int arg1,int arg2)
{
    int res = arg1 + arg2
    return res
}
```

I have no idea how to get in my main.cpp the "state" result of a function from the function who is in the other cpp file:

```
void HotplugWatcher_GUI::slotDeviceAdded(const QString &dev)
{
    qDebug("tid=%#x: add %s", (quintptr) QThread::currentThreadId(), qPrintable(dev));

    state->setText("<font color=#0000ff>Add: </font>" + dev);
    tray->showMessage(tr("New device"), dev);
}
```

so if someone can help me to understand I will appreciate

Thank you for your help guys

Comment: There's no difference between calling a function in the same file and calling a function in a different file.

Comment: However, none of the functions in the other file return any values, they're all declared `void`.

Comment: You can add a `getState()` member function to the class, and have that return the state.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want access to the 'state' member of the class.

You're best bet would be to create another function in the class the retrieves it.  For example:

```
QLabel* HotplugWatcher_GUI::getState() const
{
   return state;
}
```

But that's kind of ugly. If all you're interested in is the text, then you could do something like this:

```
QString HotplugWatcher_GUI::getStateText() const
{
   return state->text();
}
```

Comment: Ok, you could benefit from reading up on the Qt event loop and how to use it.  When you call a.exec(), you are running the application in an event loop and you can use other QObjects to talk to your hot plug watcher via signals and slots.  If you want to periodically poll the hot plug watcher, look at using a timerEvent().

Comment: you need an object (for example) `foo` of type `HotplugWatcher_GUI` and call `getStateText()` like `foo.getStateText()`. Please eat/read some Textbook about standard C++.

Comment: @Philippe, well, you have to call `HotplugWatcher_GUI::getStateText` each time the text changes. In Qt [signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) are a convinient way to get notified about such an event.

Comment: Thanks scopchanov but that is my problem, I don't know how use signal /  slot with header in project like qdeviceWatcher do...

Comment: I didn't know that will be so crazy to get just path wrote on qml Text each time we insert simple usb drive...